# Background service running continue like a media app

Tags: android, foreground

How to implement similar to "media app" foreground service for this following steps:

1. App goes to background
2. App killed from background
3. The phone is locked or the phone has gone to "idle mode"

In the above three cases the media app never stops the foreground service, without any phone activity.
We need a same case in our app, how to do that?

Comment: Have you read the official documentation of [Foreground service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services)?

Comment: any example link?

Comment: The documentation is full of example codes. Or you can easily find tutorial online with the keywords "Foreground service"

Comment: @RickyMo  I am using this: startForeground